# Change the theme of Gtk applications in a running session after KDE hijacking

Tags: kde, gtk, theme

I'm in an X11 session on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm not using a desktop environment. My window manager is Sawfish.

All of a sudden, running Gtk applications changed their appearance to what I've determined to be the Breeze theme, which is the theme used by KDE applications. This includes Sawfish's own menu, Thunderbird, Evince, Volume Control (`pavucontrol`) and Xfce4-panel. Newly started instances use this theme as well. I want them to change them back to the theme I had for Gtk.

I don't know what exactly caused this change, other than me fumbling around with KDE: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> started invoking a GUI widget which I identified to be a KDE launcher (krunner). I didn't expect that, so I kept typing in that launcher, and I don't know what I typed into it. I got rid of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> hijacking with `pkill krunner; pkill kglobalaccel5`, but the graphical theme persists.

Gnome-tweaks and xfce4-settings-manager both think by current theme is Yaru. Gnome-control-center thinks my “Appearance → Window colors” are “Standard”, whatever that means. `gtk-theme-switch2` appears to think my theme is Adwaita (or just doesn't know what the current theme is and preselects the first option in alphabetical order?) and changing to “Yaru” (or anything else) and clicking “Apply” doesn't have any visible effect.

KDE system settings (`systemsettings5`) think my theme is Breeze and doesn't offer Yaru as a choice, but that's ok — I *want* KDE applications to use KDE's theme and Gtk applications to use Gtk's theme. Switching from Breeze to Fusion in KDE system settings didn't affect Gtk applications.

`lxappearance` (an LXDE configuration tool) thinks my widget style is Breeze when it starts. I can select Yaru and click “Apply”, and this switches the theme in lxappearance itself, but it has no visible effect outside lxappearance, and if I exit lxappearance and start it again, it's back on Breeze.

```
$ grep theme ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
gtk-theme-name=Yaru
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=0
gtk-icon-theme-name=hicolor
$ grep theme ~/.gtkrc-2.0
#   /usr/share/themes/Emacs/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Yaru'
$ xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName 
Yaru
$ dconf dump / |grep -i theme
gtk-theme='Yaru'
use-theme-transparency=false
$ find .* -name .thunderbird -prune -o -name google-chrome -prune -o -type f -mmin -99 -print0 |xargs -0 grep -l -i breeze
.config/kconf_updaterc
.config/kdeglobals
.config/Trolltech.conf
.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
.kde/share/apps/color-schemes/Breeze.colors
.lesshst
```

If I start a new session in another virtual console, I see my expected colors. But I want to recover my current session. How do I do that?

What part of the system, other than the ones I tried above, control the theme used by running Gtk applications? How can I change the theme of running Gtk applications back to the theme I want?

Comment: Assuming that the important part is not losing your session: is using "save session" and doing a re-login an option?

Comment: @FelixJN “Save session” hahaha, I haven't yet seen a session saving mechanism that will restore my ~50 terminal windows with their position and shell history. And anyway, I want to understand what's going on. What mechanism did this KDE component use to tell running applications to change their theme, and what running process (presumably) still retains this information?